# Checking Dataframe for Offsetting Values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of transactions that lists the matter, the date, and the amount. People entering the data often make mistakes and have to reverse out costs by entering a new cost with a negative amount to offset the error. I'm trying to identify both reversal entries and the entry being reversed by grouping my data according to matter number and work date and then comparing Amounts.

The data looks something like this:

| MatterNum | WorkDate | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/02/2022 | 10 |
| 1 | 1/02/2022 | 15 |
| 1 | 1/02/2022 | -10 |
| 2 | 1/04/2022 | 15 |
| 2 | 1/05/2022 | -5 |
| 2 | 1/05/2022 | 5 |

So my output table would look like this:
|MatterNum|WorkDate|Amount|Reversal?|
|---------|--------|------|---------|
|1|1/02/2022|10|yes|
|1|1/02/2022|15|no|
|1|1/02/2022|-10|yes|
|2|1/04/2022|15|no|
|2|1/05/2022|-5|yes|
|2|1/05/2022|5|yes|

Right now, i'm using the following code to check each row:

```
import pandas as pd 

data = [
        [1,'1/2/2022',10],
        [1,'1/2/2022',15],
        [1,'1/2/2022',-10],
        [2,'1/4/2022',12],
        [2,'1/5/2022',-5],
        [2,'1/5/2022',5]
    ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['MatterNum','WorkDate','Amount'])

def rev_check(MatterNum, workDate, WorkAmt, df):
    funcDF = df.loc[(df['MatterNum'] == MatterNum) & (df['WorkDate'] == workDate)] 

    listCheck = funcDF['Amount'].tolist()
    if WorkAmt*-1 in listCheck:
        return 'yes'

df['reversal?'] = df.apply(lambda row: rev_check(row.MatterNum, row.WorkDate, row.Amount, df), axis=1)
```

This seems to work, but it is pretty slow. I need to check millions of rows of data. Is there a better way I can approach this that would be more efficient?

Comment: How do you define "reversal"?

Comment: Hi zac, do you mind to have a look at [ask] and try to provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Sorry, in an attempt to keep the question concise, I left out some important details. I'm currently taking each row and comparing it to other rows with the same matterNum and WorkDate. If there is an amount that is negative in the exact same amount as another entry on the same day, then I consider it a reversal. In my example, row 3 would be reversal for row 1. I need to flag both the reversal and the entry that was reversed.

Comment: @rpanai Thanks for reading my question. I read the links you provided and made some edits. Would love to hear some feedback if my question is still unclear. For what it's worth, I am trying to provide example tables in my question and they look great in the preview, but for some reason don't come through as tables when it posts.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that a "reversal" is when this row's amount is less than the previous row's amount, then pandas can do this with `diff`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
        [1,'1/2/2022',10],
        [1,'1/2/2022',15],
        [1,'1/2/2022',-10],
        [1,'1/2/2022',12]
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['MatterNum','WorkDate','Amount'])
print(df)
df['Reversal'] = df['Amount'].diff()<0
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   MatterNum  WorkDate  Amount
0          1  1/2/2022      10
1          1  1/2/2022      15
2          1  1/2/2022     -10
3          1  1/2/2022      12
   MatterNum  WorkDate  Amount  Reversal
0          1  1/2/2022      10     False
1          1  1/2/2022      15     False
2          1  1/2/2022     -10      True
3          1  1/2/2022      12     False
```

The first row has to be special-cased, since there's nothing to compare against.